# Stop Keil uvision from pushing registers on function call

Tags: c, assembly, keil

When I call a C function containing an infinite loop from main() it pushes some registers on the stack before executing that function. And since the function contains an infinite loop, those registers never gets popped.

Here's an example,

```
void My_Func (void)
{   
    int flag_1 = 1;

    while(1)
    {       
        if(counter > 5 && flag_1)
        {
            flag_1 = 0;
        }

        else if(counter > 550 && flag_1)
        {
            flag_1 = 0;
        }
   }    
}


int main(void)
{
    My_Func();

    return 0;
}
```

Here counter is a global variable.

When I call My_Func() it pushes R4, R5, R6 before executing the function. The disassembly looks like this,

```
0x080004BC B470      PUSH     {r4-r6}
```

And then the function execution starts. But since there is an infinite loop inside the function the registers never gets popped.

Is there any way to stop KEIL IDE from pushing registers before executing function, without modifying the function definition?

Comment: Yup, just edit asm file. Or insert some asm code to clear the registers for you.

Comment: `counter` is something like a [C11 `atomic_uint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic), I hope?  Otherwise the compiler is free to read it once outside the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `__attribute__((noreturn))` on the function declaration to inform the compiler that the function won't be returning. According to the [Arm Keil documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124976881.htm) this attribute is described as:

> 9.41 **__attribute__((noreturn))** function attribute
>   Informs the compiler that the function does not return. The compiler can then perform optimizations by removing code that is never reached.
>
> Usage
>   **Use this attribute to reduce the cost of calling a function** that never returns, such as exit().
>   Best practice is to always terminate non-returning functions with while(1);.

This should prevent the compiler from generating the function prologue code that pushes the registers R4 to R6.

Comment: Related: gcc implements this too, but only for ARM32 (not x86 or AArch64, or anything else AFAIK).  Also, in paths of execution in a `noreturn` function that *do* in fact return, it emits a `bx lr` or other return instruction even though the caller's registers have been clobbered.  This is just about the least useful thing it could do for this Undefined Behaviour.  ([gcc bug 82158](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82158) = wontfix).   It could have saved code size by not emitting code for for asm basic blocks that end with a return.  Or emit a trap.

Comment: Anyway, if you get this wrong on gcc and ignore the compiler warning, and your program does actually take the path that leads to the UB, prepare for silent corruption of program state.  (It's not UB to compile a function that has some paths that return from a `noreturn` function: it's only UB if execution takes those paths at run-time).   Anyway, this is why Keil suggests putting an infloop on paths that would return, because that's easier to debug than returning with corrupt registers.  (Assuming it's like gcc).